# android folder is missing in the flutter plugin I was trying to create

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

[image: flutter plugin]

Actually, I'd like to create a plugin which controls the volume of different sounds playing together, separately, but when I started the `android` folder was missing, I am trying for a very long but was not able to find the solution yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] it and copy-paste the code in between \`\`\` the_code \`\`\`

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following inside the `example` folder:

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux,ios,android,web .
```

Remove whenever platform not needed in the list.